# Connect to SQL Server 2008 from Webhost PHP file?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

Can anyone point me in the right direction for connecting to a SQL Server 2008 database from my website via php?

I would assume its not much different then connecting to a MySQL server.. Any help please, Thanks

Comment: -1 Googling "php sql server" isn't exactly void of results, and StackOverflow isn't a tutorial finding service.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the script you need...

More on it at http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

```
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and for the other guy that posted.. I know its not a tutorial finding service.. I already searched for the information just there are alot of different results.. I posted on here in hopes someone could narrow down what I need to find..  Should I use "odbc_connect" or "sqlsrv_connect" or another.. anyway.. Gonna check out what Nick posted..

Answer (score 0):

Look into the MS SQL Server PDO interface:

- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Comment: That should only be used if you're connecting from linux.  On a Windows server, you would want to the official Microsoft SQL driver for PDO.

Answer (score 0):

I would warn you, it's not a fantastic thing connecting SQL Server 2008 with PHP. I did succeed once, though it was on my local machine running windows. Have a look at the microsoft tutorial on how to connect SQL Server 2008 with PHP here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx and the link below will guide you as well. Good luck.
http://hafizbadrie.wordpress.com/2010/02/16/how-to-connect-php-with-sql-server-2008/

Comment: As long as you're on a Windows box, it's a 5 minute thing.